# mysqldb python ошибка установки

Tags: python, mysql

Хочу установить библиотеку mysqldb, с которой работал год назад.
Пытаюсь установит через Anaconda.
В Anaconda ставится через команду: `pip install MySQLdb`

Ошибка:

```
Collecting MySQLdb

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQLdb (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for MySQLdb
```

Что поддержку библиотеку прекратили?

Comment: pip install mysqlclient. А пакета MySQLdb на PyPI и не существовало никогда, вы просто запутались

Answer (score 1):

Для Python3:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Для Python2:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте прописать команду полностью

```
python -m pip install MySQLdb
```

И посмотрите в этом направлении:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface/33928783#33928783